# Get value of checked checkbox and the respective images

Tags: jquery

I have wrote a function to set the value of checked checkbox and the respective images like on check of one checkbox some images will display and on check of another checkbox some other images will display. And on check of all checkboxes all the respective images will display. I am getting error in this function. Please help me out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>onclick get images using array</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style type="text/css">
    .main {
        background-color: #5F9EA0;
    }

    .main1 {
        background-color: #5F9EA0;
        padding: 50px 30px;
    }

    .main h2 {
        color: #ffff;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .imageback {
        background-color: #afcecf;
        padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
    }

    button {
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #ffa333;
        padding: 8px 25px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #ffff;
        font-size: 18px;
        margin: 15px 0;
    }

    .imagename1, .imagename2, .imagename3 {
        display: none;
    }

    .imagename1 h4, .imagename2 h4, .imagename3 h4  {
        color: #ffff;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: 50px 0;
    }

    #mainimage1, #mainimage2, #mainimage3 {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    label {
        color: #ffff;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    .stylevaluee {
        background-color: #5F9EA0;
        padding: 50px 0px;
    }

    .stylevaluee li {
        color: #ffff;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 16px;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 5px 0;
    }
</style>

<body>
<header>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 main">
                <h2 class="text-center">OnClick make gallery using Multiple Arrays</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>



<section class="imageback">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="col-lg-2 main1">
                <form name="myform1" action="/action_page.php">
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label><input type="checkbox" name="interior" value="Style the Sofa">Style the Sofa</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label><input type="checkbox" name="interior" value="Style the Bed">Style the Bed</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label><input type="checkbox" name="interior" value="Style the Kitchen">Style the Kitchen</label>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 imageback1">
            <div class="imagemain1">
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename1">
                <img id="myimage0" class="img-responsive" src="images/images1/sofa1.jpg">
                <h4 id="head0" class="text-center">Two color sofa</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename1">
                <img id="myimage1" class="img-responsive" src="images/images1/sofa2.jpg">
                <h4 id="head1" class="text-center">Velvet italian style Sofa</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename1">
                <img id="myimage2" class="img-responsive" src="images/images1/sofa3.jpg">
                <h4 id="head2" class="text-center">White Sofa Modern</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename1">
                <img id="myimage3" class="img-responsive" src="images/images1/sofa4.jpg">
                <h4 id="head3" class="text-center">Yellow sofa Wallpaper</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename1">
                <img id="myimage4" class="img-responsive" src="images/images1/sofa5.jpg">
                <h4 id="head4" class="text-center">Pure leather sofa</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename1">
                <img id="myimage5" class="img-responsive" src="images/images1/sofa6.jpg">
                <h4 id="head5" class="text-center">White american style sofa</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="imagemain2">
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename2">
                <img id="myimage0" class="img-responsive" src="images/images2/bed1.jpg">
                <h4 id="head0" class="text-center">Brown color bed</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename2">
                <img id="myimage1" class="img-responsive" src="images/images2/bed2.jpg">
                <h4 id="head1" class="text-center">Italian style bed</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename2">
                <img id="myimage2" class="img-responsive" src="images/images2/bed3.jpg">
                <h4 id="head2" class="text-center">White/black color bed</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename2">
                <img id="myimage3" class="img-responsive" src="images/images2/bed4.jpg">
                <h4 id="head3" class="text-center">Red color bed</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename2">
                <img id="myimage4" class="img-responsive" src="images/images2/bed5.jpg">
                <h4 id="head4" class="text-center">Pure light green bed</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename2">
                <img id="myimage5" class="img-responsive" src="images/images2/bed6.jpg">
                <h4 id="head5" class="text-center">Milky color bed</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="imagemain3">
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename3">
                <img id="myimage0" class="img-responsive" src="images/images3/kitchen1.jpg">
                <h4 id="head0" class="text-center">Dark black pannels style</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename3">
                <img id="myimage1" class="img-responsive" src="images/images3/kitchen2.jpg">
                <h4 id="head1" class="text-center">Italian milky style</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename3">
                <img id="myimage2" class="img-responsive" src="images/images3/kitchen3.jpg">
                <h4 id="head2" class="text-center">light and dark green style</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename3">
                <img id="myimage3" class="img-responsive" src="images/images3/kitchen4.jpg">
                <h4 id="head3" class="text-center">Red and black pannels style</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename3">
                <img id="myimage4" class="img-responsive" src="images/images3/kitchen5.jpg">
                <h4 id="head4" class="text-center">Pure colorfull style</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename3">
                <img id="myimage5" class="img-responsive" src="images/images3/kitchen6.jpg">
                <h4 id="head5" class="text-center">Wooden style kitchen</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <ul id="stylevalue" class="stylevaluee">

                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>



<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("[name=interior]").click(function (){
    myFunction();
  });

  function myFunction() {
    var pix = $(".imageback1 > div")
  var total = "<ul>";
    $("[name=interior]:checked").each(function(){
        total += "<li>" + $(this).val() + "</li>";
    });

    total += "</ul>";
    alert(total);
    $("#stylevalue").html(total);

    if (total = "Style the Sofa") {
        $(".imagename1").fadeIn(1000);
    }

    else (total = "Style the Bed") {
        $(".imagename2").fadeIn(1000);
    }

    else (total = "Style the Kitchen") {
        $(".imagename3").fadeIn(1000);
    }
}
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: function is not working

Answer (score 0):

You got lot of `syntax` error *!* , if you want to use equal, you should use `==` or `===` not `=`, single means `define` also in your condition `if` and `else if` is totally wrong, you used two `else` not `else if` and more `unexpected` errors, check this out below snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[name=interior]").click(function() {
    myFunction();
  });

  function myFunction() {
    var pix = $(".imageback1 > div")
    var total = "<ul>";
    $("[name=interior]:checked").each(function() {
      total += "<li>" + $(this).val() + "</li>";
      alert($(this).val())
      if ($(this).val() == "Style the Sofa") {
        $(".imagename1").fadeIn(1000);
      } else if ($(this).val() == "Style the Bed") {
        $(".imagename2").fadeIn(1000);
      } else if ($(this).val() == "Style the Kitchen") {
        $(".imagename3").fadeIn(1000);
      }
    });

    total += "</ul>";

    $("#stylevalue").html(total);
  }
});
```

```css
.main {
  background-color: #5F9EA0;
}

.main1 {
  background-color: #5F9EA0;
  padding: 50px 30px;
}

.main h2 {
  color: #ffff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.imageback {
  background-color: #afcecf;
  padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
}

button {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffa333;
  padding: 8px 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffff;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.imagename1,
.imagename2,
.imagename3 {
  display: none;
}

.imagename1 h4,
.imagename2 h4,
.imagename3 h4 {
  color: #ffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 50px 0;
}

#mainimage1,
#mainimage2,
#mainimage3 {
  cursor: pointer;
}

label {
  color: #ffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.stylevaluee {
  background-color: #5F9EA0;
  padding: 50px 0px;
}

.stylevaluee li {
  color: #ffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 main">
        <h2 class="text-center">OnClick make gallery using Multiple Arrays</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>



<section class="imageback">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-lg-2 main1">
          <form name="myform1" action="/action_page.php">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" name="interior" value="Style the Sofa">Style the Sofa</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" name="interior" value="Style the Bed">Style the Bed</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" name="interior" value="Style the Kitchen">Style the Kitchen</label>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 imageback1">
          <div class="imagemain1">
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename1">
              <img id="myimage0" class="img-responsive" alt="1sas" src="images/images1/sofa1.jpg">
              <h4 id="head0" class="text-center">Two color sofa</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename1">
              <img id="myimage1" class="img-responsive" src="images/images1/sofa2.jpg">
              <h4 id="head1" class="text-center">Velvet italian style Sofa</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename1">
              <img id="myimage2" class="img-responsive" src="images/images1/sofa3.jpg">
              <h4 id="head2" class="text-center">White Sofa Modern</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename1">
              <img id="myimage3" class="img-responsive" src="images/images1/sofa4.jpg">
              <h4 id="head3" class="text-center">Yellow sofa Wallpaper</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename1">
              <img id="myimage4" class="img-responsive" src="images/images1/sofa5.jpg">
              <h4 id="head4" class="text-center">Pure leather sofa</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename1">
              <img id="myimage5" class="img-responsive" src="images/images1/sofa6.jpg">
              <h4 id="head5" class="text-center">White american style sofa</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="imagemain2">
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename2">
              <img id="myimage0" class="img-responsive" src="images/images2/bed1.jpg">
              <h4 id="head0" class="text-center">Brown color bed</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename2">
              <img id="myimage1" class="img-responsive" src="images/images2/bed2.jpg">
              <h4 id="head1" class="text-center">Italian style bed</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename2">
              <img id="myimage2" class="img-responsive" src="images/images2/bed3.jpg">
              <h4 id="head2" class="text-center">White/black color bed</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename2">
              <img id="myimage3" class="img-responsive" src="images/images2/bed4.jpg">
              <h4 id="head3" class="text-center">Red color bed</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename2">
              <img id="myimage4" class="img-responsive" src="images/images2/bed5.jpg">
              <h4 id="head4" class="text-center">Pure light green bed</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename2">
              <img id="myimage5" class="img-responsive" src="images/images2/bed6.jpg">
              <h4 id="head5" class="text-center">Milky color bed</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="imagemain3">
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename3">
              <img id="myimage0" class="img-responsive" src="images/images3/kitchen1.jpg">
              <h4 id="head0" class="text-center">Dark black pannels style</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename3">
              <img id="myimage1" class="img-responsive" src="images/images3/kitchen2.jpg">
              <h4 id="head1" class="text-center">Italian milky style</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename3">
              <img id="myimage2" class="img-responsive" src="images/images3/kitchen3.jpg">
              <h4 id="head2" class="text-center">light and dark green style</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename3">
              <img id="myimage3" class="img-responsive" src="images/images3/kitchen4.jpg">
              <h4 id="head3" class="text-center">Red and black pannels style</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename3">
              <img id="myimage4" class="img-responsive" src="images/images3/kitchen5.jpg">
              <h4 id="head4" class="text-center">Pure colorfull style</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 imagename3">
              <img id="myimage5" class="img-responsive" src="images/images3/kitchen6.jpg">
              <h4 id="head5" class="text-center">Wooden style kitchen</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
          <ul id="stylevalue" class="stylevaluee">

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Also for making work what you ask in your question, you need to move your condition inside of `loop` also compare `$(this).val` not `total`